# grep regex : extract pattern from all files in a directory

Tags: regex, grep

Lets say a directory has two files. Here are the contents

File1.txt

```
tagstart random string tagend

tagstart random string tagend
```

File2.txt

```
tagstart random string tagend

tagstart random string tagend
```

I want to grep the directory and extract the lines that have the following pattern

```
tagstart <any string> tagend
```

I also want to pipe the output to another file. Basically the grep command will result in an output file like this

out.txt

```
tagstart random string tagend

tagstart random string tagend

tagstart random string tagend

tagstart random string tagend
```

Comment: your pattern doesn't match your file contents at all - can you clarify your question?

Comment: Regexes are rarely a good way to parse xml.    
Have you thought about situations like `<tag>one<tag>two</tag>one</tag>`? What kind of result do you want from such an input?

Comment: basically I want to extract all tag occurences that have any strings between the start and end of the tags

Comment: posted as an answer for proper formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file1.txt:

```
# This is the file nr.1
tagstart 123 tagend
tagstart abc tagend
kill tagstart def tagend kenny
```

file2.txt:

```
# This is the file nr.2
tagstart 123 tagend
tagstart abc tagend
kill tagstart xxx tagend kenny
```

This command will extract the tags and their enclosed strings:

```
 cat file1.txt file2.txt | grep -o -E "tagstart(.*?)tagend" > output.txt
```

output.txt:

```
tagstart 123 tagend
tagstart abc tagend
tagstart def tagend
tagstart 123 tagend
tagstart abc tagend
tagstart xxx tagend
```

*Extra cookie for your pleasure:*

This command will do something similar, but will display only sorted unique records, and they occurrences (for statistics purpose):

```
 sort file1.txt file2.txt | grep -o -E "tagstart(.*?)tagend" | uniq -c | \
 awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4" : "$1}' > output.txt
```

output.txt:

```
tagstart 123 tagend : 2
tagstart abc tagend : 2
tagstart def tagend : 1
tagstart xxx tagend : 1
```

Comment: the log file may have other unwanted information too. Let me be more specific. I am looking for a regex that will extract any string between the tags

Comment: Thanks Andrejs. One slight twist to it
what if file1.txt has this

some nonsense before start tagstart xyz tagend nonsense after end

I still want to extract only 'tagstart xyz tagend'

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'tagstart random string tagend' file1.txt file2.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Jim, my question was not clear previously. I edited the question. The pattern I am looking for is any string that can occur between the tags

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are rarely a good way to parse xml. Have you thought about situations like `tagstart one tagstart two tagend one tagend`?

`tagstart one tagstart two tagend one tagend`
or
`tagstart one tagstart two tagend`
or
`tagstart two tagend`
or
`tagstart two tagend one tagend`
all satisfy your criteria. Which of these do you want?

Comment: thanks kaestur. My log files don't have such tag structures. I am looking for a regex that will extract any string between the tags